# Why does my looping variable not convert to a string?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have written a Python code to scrape from a website for certain years. To this end, I have created a for loop to iterate over the years and use the string to navigate to the website. See below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import pandas as pd

URL = 'url'    
for year in range(2012,2021):
    type(year)
    stryear = str(year)

    driver.get(URL + stryear)
    content = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content,features="lxml")

#Rest of code
```

For some reason, the first iteration is all fine. When running the debug mode, I see that in the second iteration, the variable year is an integer with value 2013 (as expected). The variable stryear however, gets type {Resultset: 0} [], with source {SoupStrainer} 2013|{}.

Obviously, I am not declaring stryear anywhere else in the code. I need stryear to be a string containing the year. Why is the variable stryear not behaving as I expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your imports. Most probably `str()` was either imported locally from Soup library or got `monkey patched` by it globally.

Comment: Indeed, by using stryear = year.__str__() the code does work